# ¿Cómo extraer dos variables de una string separadas por un signo?

Tags: java

Tengo que escribir una calculadora en java. Se introduce texto en una string de esta forma: "12.3+22.12". ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se distinga entre el primer y segundo término al mismo tiempo que reconozco que tipo de operación se debe realizar (Suma, resta, multiplicación o división). He pensado que se podrían extraer tres variables; una con el primer término, una con el segundo y otra con el operador, para luego usar un switch. Pero no sé como hacer esto primero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
//este String es el que recibes    
String numero = "12*22.12";
double num1 = 0;
double num2 = 0;
String[] array = null;
//Se busca en el String que simbolo contiene
if(numero.contains("+")){
    //Se hace un Split para dividir al String
    array = numero.split("\\+");
    num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
    num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
    //Se hace la suma
    System.out.println("La suma es: " + (num1+num2));
}else if(numero.contains("-")){
    array = numero.split("-");
    num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
    num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
    System.out.println("La resta es: " + (num1-num2));
}else if(numero.contains("*")){
    array = numero.split("\\*");
    num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
    num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
    System.out.println("La multiplicación es: " + (num1*num2));
}else if(numero.contains("/")){
    array = numero.split("/");
    num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
    num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
    System.out.println("La division es: " + (num1/num2));
}
```